# Partial results from spark Async Interface?

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to cancel an spark future and still get a smaller RDD with the processed elements?

Spark Async Actions "documented" here

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.AsyncRDDActions

And the future itself has a rich set of functions

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.FutureAction

The use case I was thinking of is to have a very huge map, that could be aborted afted 30 minutes of calculation, and still collect -or even iterate or saveAsObjectFile- the subset of the RDD that has been effectively mapped.

Answer (score 2):

`FutureAction.cancel` causes a failure (see [comment in JobWaiter.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.3.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/JobWaiter.scala#L44)), so you cannot use it to get partial results. I don't think there's a way to do it through the async API.

Instead, you could stop processing the input after 30 minutes.

```
val stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis + 30 * 60 * 1000 // 30 minutes from now.
rdd.mapPartitions { partition =>
  if (System.currentTimeMillis < stopTime) partition.map {
    // Process it like usual.
    ???
  } else {
    // Time's up. Don't process anything.
    Iterator()
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that this only makes a difference once all the shuffle dependencies have completed. (It cannot stop the shuffle from being performed, even when 30 minutes have passed.)

Comment: :-) I guess that all the async functions are also untested, at least in production sites.